# Repeating notifications not repeating in watchOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, watchos

I am trying to implement repeating notifications in my watchOS app.

Here is the code:

```
      let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
      content.title = "tap"
      content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
      let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval, repeats: true)
      let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in 
      })
```

On the real device everything seams to work correctly: I receive a notification every time the interval passes. But on the simulator I see strange behavior: everything works fine if I tap `dismiss` on every notification when I receive it. But if I don't tap `dismiss`, I receive two notifications and then stop receiving them. Here is how it looks:

[image]

I am afraid the app could behave the same way in real life under some circumstances, so I want to fix this.

It Is also a thing that both notifications appear to have the same time on the screenshot, despite the fact that two minutes have passed between them. Looks like watchOS doesn't distinguish them as they both have the same ID. But it is not clear how am I supposed to create multiple IDs for them as they are actually a part of one repeating notification.

One of ways to fix this could be creating multiple non-repeating notifications, but as I have read there is a limit of 64 of them, and I need more.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately don't know a solution but am with you spiritually 